# How to guarantee the stdout buffer between systemd and journald is flushed when program quits?

Tags: buffer, stdout, systemd, systemd-journald

The simplified example that demonstrates a problem is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("foo\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

(it's not programming language specific though - the original application I discovered the problem with is in Go).

If it's compiled and is run by the following unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=description
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/binary

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then on `systemctl restart` `journald` would in most cases not get the `foo\n` output, while `syslog` successfully writes it down to the `/var/log/syslog`.

Here is the example of the `journald` output for the service:

```
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename
May 18 08:30:38 hostname servicename[7701]: foo
May 18 08:30:41 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename
May 18 08:30:41 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename
May 18 08:30:46 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename
May 18 08:30:46 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename
```

and then the corresponding part of the `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename.
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename.
May 18 08:30:38 hostname servicename[7682]: foo
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename.
May 18 08:30:38 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename.
May 18 08:30:38 hostname servicename[7701]: foo
May 18 08:30:41 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename.
May 18 08:30:41 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename.
May 18 08:30:41 hostname servicename[7720]: foo
May 18 08:30:46 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped servicename.
May 18 08:30:46 hostname systemd[1]: Started servicename.
May 18 08:30:46 hostname servicename[7739]: foo
```

What would be a way to **guarantee** journald received the `stdout`, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr, it's a known issue.

I asked the same question at the [systemd-devel maillist](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel) and got a [reply](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-May/040775.html) with a reference to the [reported issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913).